# I'm trying to create a quiz with JSP and I can't get my radio button to work for multiple questions

Tags: mysql, jsp, radio-button

I got 10 questions where each question got 4 options(40 options in total)the problem is that i'm only able to **check the radio button for one option out of all 40 options** in the quiz..how am I suppose to give radio button for four options separately...thanks in advance.** [code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m21hE.png)**

Comment: Try changing your radio button name dynamically in your loop. e.g "q1a" for first question and "q2a" for second question and so on.

Comment: yeah doing that will get back to you..thank you :) muja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code, you are assigning the same name to 40 radio buttons.

Please assign a different name to different groups.

name "q1a" is assigned to all the radio buttons. change it for a different group.

Then it will work..!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer..that makes sense...how i have to give different for each option since i'm defining it in a loop.